# Can't Change User-Agent in Splash (LUA) - Having Error: Lua error: [string "function main(splash, args) ..."]:12: assertion failed

Tags: lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I was trying to login to Google account using Splash. I was successfuly logged in and then it returned me an error "Browser Not Supported". i.e

[image: 1]

So to cover this, i went to change the user agent in splash. I added the following code

```
splash:set_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405")
```

But unfortunately, it returned me an error:

```
{
"error": 400,
"type": "ScriptError",
"description": "Error happened while executing Lua script",
"info": {
    "source": "[string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]",
    "line_number": 12,
    "error": "assertion failed!",
    "type": "LUA_ERROR",
    "message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]:12: assertion failed!"
    }
}
```

I don't know what's going on, I also tried 2 more different ways to add user agent but same error every time.

Here is the Full LUA code:

```
 function main(splash, args)
  

  
  splash:set_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405")
  assert(splash:wait(2))

  url = args.url
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(2))
  input_box = assert(splash:select('#identifierId'))
  input_box:focus()
  input_box:send_text('email')
  assert(splash:wait(2))
  input_box:send_keys("<Enter>")
  assert(splash:wait(3))
  
  pass = assert(splash:select(".whsOnd"))
  pass:focus()
  pass:send_text('pass')
  assert(splash:wait(2))
  pass:send_keys("<Enter>")
  assert(splash:wait(15))
  


  

 
  
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
  }
end
```

Let me know if someone has solution for it. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you tag this with python. also please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting.

Comment: ok thanks, i read this. Also, sorry about python tag. I forgot about that, because i was working with python.

Comment: Try usual UserAgent string (such as FireFox on Windows10).

Comment: Tried that also, but same error.